# Postgres/Redshift Count last 5 rows by status

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table A:

```
id, pid, status
---------------
1 | x |   3
2 | x |   2
3 | y |   0
4 | y |   1
5 | z |   3
6 | y |   1
7 | x |   2
8 | z |   3
```

What I need is to grouped by `pid` count how many of the last 5 rows (ordered by id) have status 3.

So what I'm trying to get is:

```
pid, is_3
---------
x  | 1
y  | 0
z  | 2
```

I am trying to achieve this with a query like:

```
SELECT pid, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN 1 END) AS is_3 
FROM A 
GROUP BY pid 
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 5;
```

Note that I try to get the last 5 rows for a given `pid` by ordering by id, because id is a sequence here.

But I get an Error `ERROR:  column "A.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Obviously I'm terrible at SQL. Any thoughts on how to best achieve this performance-oriented if possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you can use a window function to get the row number (similar to aggregate but not actually), then filter

```
select pid, sum(case when status=3 then 1 else 0 end) as status_3_cnt
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by pid order by id desc)  
    from your_table
)
where row_number<=5
group by 1
```

more about window functions in this [article](https://blog.statsbot.co/sql-window-functions-tutorial-b5075b87d129)